# What kind of python magic does dir() perform with __getattr__?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following is in python 2.7 with MySQLdb 1.2.3.

I needed a class wrapper to add some attributes to objects which didn't support it (classes with `__slots__` and/or some class written in C) so I came out with something like this:

```
class Wrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._wrapped_obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, obj):
        return getattr(self._wrapped_obj, attr)
```

I was expecting that the `dir()` builtin called on my instance of `Wrapper` should have returned just the names inherited by object plus `wrapped_obj`, and I discovered that this is actually the case for *most* cases, but not for all. I tried this with a custom old style class, a custom new style class, and some builtin classes, it always worked this way: the only exception that i found is when the wrapped object was an instance of the class `_mysql.connection`. In this case, `dir()` on my object happens to know also all the method names attached to the wrapped connection object.

I read in the python documentation about `dir`, and this behaviour appears to be legit: `dir` is supposed to return a list of "interesting names", not the "real" content of the instance. But I really can't figure how it does this: it actually understands the implementation of my `__getattr__` and resolves to the attached item? If this is true, why only with that `connection` class and not for instance with a simpler `dict`?

Here is some pasted code as an example of this curious behaviour:

```
>>> from _mysql import connection
>>> c = connection(**connection_parameters)
>>> c
<_mysql.connection open to '127.0.0.1' at a16920>
>>> 
>>> dir(c)
['affected_rows', 'autocommit', 'change_user', 'character_set_name', 'close', 'commit', 'dump_debug_info', 'errno', 'error', 'escape', 'escape_string', 'field_count', 'get_character_set_info', 'get_host_info', 'get_proto_info', 'get_server_info', 'info', 'insert_id', 'kill', 'next_result', 'ping', 'query', 'rollback', 'select_db', 'set_character_set', 'set_server_option', 'shutdown', 'sqlstate', 'stat', 'store_result', 'string_literal', 'thread_id', 'use_result', 'warning_count']
>>> 
>>> w = Wrapper(c)
>>> dir(w)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_wrapped_obj', 'affected_rows', 'autocommit', 'change_user', 'character_set_name', 'close', 'commit', 'dump_debug_info', 'errno', 'error', 'escape', 'escape_string', 'field_count', 'get_character_set_info', 'get_host_info', 'get_proto_info', 'get_server_info', 'info', 'insert_id', 'kill', 'next_result', 'ping', 'query', 'rollback', 'select_db', 'set_character_set', 'set_server_option', 'shutdown', 'sqlstate', 'stat', 'store_result', 'string_literal', 'thread_id', 'use_result', 'warning_count']
>>> 
>>> d = Wrapper({})
>>> dir(d)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_wrapped_obj']
>>>
```

Comment: I cannot actually reproduce what you are seeing on Python 2.7 and MySQLdb. `dir(w)` does **not** include the names from `c`.

Comment: Are you certain you didn't include a `__dir__` method on your wrapper that returns `dir(self._wrapped_obj)`?

Comment: yes I do, i tested the pasted output with the Wrapper class just as defined above

Comment: What does `import _mysql; print _mysql.version_info` produce?

Comment: `(1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)`

Comment: I tested this with 1.2.5 here. Does any of `c.__dir__`, `c.__members__` and `c.__methods__` return anything?

Comment: I cannot reproduce myself too. Python 2.6.7, _mysql.version_info >>> (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)

Comment: >>> c.__methods__
    ['affected_rows', 'autocommit', 'change_user', 'character_set_name', 'close', 'commit', 'dump_debug_info', 'errno', 'error', 'escape', 'escape_string', 'field_count', 'get_character_set_info', 'get_host_info', 'get_proto_info', 'get_server_info', 'info', 'insert_id', 'kill', 'next_result', 'ping', 'query', 'rollback', 'select_db', 'set_character_set', 'set_server_option', 'shutdown', 'sqlstate', 'stat', 'store_result', 'string_literal', 'thread_id', 'use_result', 'warning_count']
    >>>

Comment: c.__dir__ and c.__members__ raise AttributeError

Comment: Bingo, it is `__methods__`, a deprecated attribute that your version still has and mine doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two deprecated attributes in Python 2, [`object.__members__` and `object.__methods__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__methods__); these were aimed at supporting `dir()` on extension types (C-defined objects):

> `object.__methods__`
>   Deprecated since version 2.2: Use the built-in function `dir()` to get a list of an object’s attributes. This attribute is no longer available.
>
> `object.__members__`
>   Deprecated since version 2.2: Use the built-in function dir() to get a list of an object’s attributes. This attribute is no longer available.

These were removed from Python 3, but because your connection object (at leasts in the older version you are using) still provides a `__methods__` attribute that is found *through your `__getattr__` hook* and used by `dir()` here.

If you add a `print` statement to the `__getattr__` method you'll see the attributes being accessed:

```
>>> class Wrapper(object):
...     def __init__(self, obj):
...         self._wrapped_obj = obj
...     def __getattr__(self, obj):
...         print 'getattr', obj
...         return getattr(self._wrapped_obj, attr)
... 
>>> dir(Wrapper({}))
getattr __members__
getattr __methods__
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_wrapped_obj']
```

For new-style objects, the newer [`__dir__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) supported by `dir()` is properly looked up on the type only so you don't see that being accessed here.

The [project HISTORY file](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/HISTORY) suggests the attributes were removed in the big Python 3 compatibility update for 1.2.4 beta 1.